# NSURLConnection always timeout downloading files from amazon cloudfront under IOS 9 with 3g/4g cellular network

Tags: ios, ios9, amazon-cloudfront

I used NSURLConnection in my ios app downloading files from amazon cloudfront. It worked fine before ios 9.
Since we didn't get our server ready with ATS,  we bypassed ats to make our app work for ios 9 as below:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

This works fine under WiFi network. It can download any file from amazon cloudfront. But when switched to 3g/4g, it always timeout when downloading the same file(s).  I tested it on ios8 and it worked fine for 3g/4g.
(I used  http://d1cuipghlrk1ey.cloudfront.net/audio/word/tou2-fa.mp3 for testing.  note: http not https)
The related code snippet is quite simple. I past below

```
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[self.connection start];
```

btw, problem still exists in the the latest update of 9.0.1
I suspect it's a bug with ios9.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>YOURHOST.COM</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>1.0</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: But, I already used "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" which totally disabled ats. That still didn't work.